# How to set minor ticks in plotly

Tags: javascript, plotly

How can I create minor ticks in plotly?
Minor ticks have shorter tick lengths and not labelled.
Can one specify a frequency, like 4 minor ticks between major ticks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see below code for an example. You will need to use the minor attribute to set this. The length is controlled by `ticklen`, color by `tickcolor`, number of ticks by `nticks`, position (inside/outside) by `minor_ticks` and so on. More information is available [here](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/xaxis/#layout-xaxis-minor).

**Code**

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="total_bill", y="tip", color="sex")
fig.update_xaxes(minor=dict(ticklen=6, tickcolor="black", tickmode='auto', nticks=10, showgrid=True))
fig.update_yaxes(minor_ticks="inside")
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thx. Do you have also a javascript version? Currently, I'm trying to translated it.

Answer (score 1):

So here is the javascript version for minor ticks:

```js
var data = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  y: [3, 4, 1, 6, 3],
};
var layout = {
  yaxis: {
    ticks: 'inside',
    ticklen: 10,
    tickcolor: 'black',
    minor: {
      ticks: 'inside',
      ticklen: 6,
      tickcolor: 'black'
    }
  }
};
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', [data], layout);
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.14.0.min.js'></script>
<div id='myDiv'></div>
```

It seems `minor_ticks='inside'` works in python, but not in js. In js it should be `minor: {ticks: 'inside'}`.

PS: I just figured out it works with https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.14.0.min.js, but not with
https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js (v1.58.5).