# Error when trying to set minor grid in plotly

Tags: plotly

I try to set minor ticks in a plotly plot but the code that is presented in ["How to set minor ticks in plotly"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73756610/how-to-set-minor-ticks-in-plotly/73756870#73756870?newreg=8e222322a0d34ddfac1f3dd6a30c56e0) or in the [official documentation](https://plotly.com/python/axes/#adding-minor-ticks) does not work for me because plotly does not seem to know what the minor property of the update axis function is.

[Output with my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/770pX.jpg)

[Output with the Stackoverflow solution code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oc2jJ.jpg)

Here is the solution code from ["How to set minor ticks in plotly"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73756610/how-to-set-minor-ticks-in-plotly/73756870#73756870?newreg=8e222322a0d34ddfac1f3dd6a30c56e0).

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="total_bill", y="tip", color="sex")
fig.update_xaxes(minor=dict(ticklen=6, tickcolor="black", tickmode='auto', nticks=10, showgrid=True))
fig.update_yaxes(minor_ticks="inside")
fig.show()
```

Comment: The minor grid was implemented in version plotly 5.8. Is your current version plotly 5.8 or higher?

Comment: Okay thank you now i got version 5.10 and it works, conda auto installed version 5.6 for some reason.