# no minor tick setting for plotly go.Figure?

Tags: python, plotly

when using plotly express, we can set minor tick like below post

[How to set minor ticks in plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73756610/how-to-set-minor-ticks-in-plotly)

However, when using go.Figure(), It tried like in below manual and I got an error, so how to set minor tick for date axis in go.Figure()? Thanks

https://plotly.com/python/time-series/

```py
fig.update_xaxes(autorange=False,range=[start_date_dts_heatmap_prod,end_date_dts_heatmap_prod_1],
                 tickfont=dict(size=tick_font_size),
                 ticklabelmode= "period", 
                 tickcolor= "black", 
                 ticklen=10, 
                 minor=dict(
                    ticklen=4,  
                    dtick=7*24*60*60*1000,  
                    tick0=start_date_dts_heatmap_prod, 
                    griddash='dot', 
                    gridcolor='white'),
                 row=3,col=1
                 )  #autorange=False,range=y_range,row=2,col=1
```

```
ValueError: Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.layout.XAxis: 'minor'

Did you mean "mirror"?
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are updating the layout, axes, etc for a fig returned by a `px` function, in fact you are working with `plotly.graph_objects`. Hence your question is not quite clear.

This simple example shows that minor ticks are drawn:

```
fig=go.Figure(go.Scatter(x=[1,2,3,4,5], y=[0.2, 0.75, 1.3, 1.0, 0.57]),
             go.Layout(width=450, height=400))

fig.update_xaxes(minor=dict(
                        ticklen=4,  
                        dtick=0.5,  
                        ))
```

[image: minor-ticks-plotly]

To get all attributes of `minor`, print:

```
help(go.layout.XAxis.minor)
```

Are you working with the last plotly.py version?
If not, install it via pip:

```
pip install plotly --upgrade
```